# WordPress loading javascript with strange character set

Tags: javascript, wordpress, character-encoding

I'm using WordPress 5.1 with Yoast SEO. Yoast SEO relies on the file components.js which is throwing the following error in the console (I've edited this for brevity - it's a very long string)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: 
/[A-Za-zÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ÆºÆ»Æ¼-Æ¿Ç€-ÇƒÇ„-Ê“Ê”Ê•-Ê¯Ê°-Ê¸Ê»-ËË-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë®Í°-Í³Í¶-Í·ÍºÍ»-Í½Í¿Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î
```

The identical string does not appear in the file, though the file does include the following line when looking with a text editor:

```
["+"A-Za-zÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ÆºÆ»Æ¼-Æ¿Ç€-ÇƒÇ„-Ê“Ê”Ê•-Ê¯Ê°-Ê¸Ê»-ËË-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë®Í°-Í³Í¶-Í·ÍºÍ
```

The line looks like this when looking through the webhost control panel:

```
["+"A-Za-zªµºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ƺƻƼ-ƿǀ-ǃǄ-ʓʔʕ-ʯʰ-ʸʻ-ˁː-ˑˠ-ˤˮͰ-ͳͶ-ͷͺͻ-ͽͿΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ϵϷ-ҁ҂Ҋ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙ՚-՟ա-և։ःऄ-हऻ
```

The only odd thing is that the database had a mix of character sets (latin1, utf8 and utf8mb4) which I have attempted to fix and all tables now use utf8mb4_uncode_ci (this was chosen as it was the most common character set in the db).

There is also a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM table types. The site has a number of `Â` characters around the site which is a common indicator of character set issues as far as I can tell.

So I'm guessing for some reason WordPress is loading the javascript file with the incorrect character set which is creating errors.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm a bit baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

This was due to `blog_charset` being set to `UTF-7` in `wp_options`. Changing this to `UTF-8` has solved the problem